# Custom font change for textview in custom listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, custom-font, custom-lists

I have a custom list with one image view and one text view.
I want to change textview font to custom font in assests folder.

I am using Fragments so getAssests method is not working in Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
Typeface typeface = typeface.createFromAsset(.getAssets(), "fonts/SWINSBRG.TTF");
```